# What is the best practice of using {literal} in smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

Consider the following two block of smarty code and let me know which one is best practice.

```
{literal}<script type="text/javascript">
    // JavaScript Code Goes Here
</script>{/literal}
```

or the below one,

```
<script type="text/javascript">{literal}
    // JavaScript Code Goes Here
{/literal}</script>
```

Comment: Have you read the docs https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal ??

Comment: Just read it and got my answer. You can post your comment as an answer. If i do not get more answer with further information, i will accept it as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference where to use this, because {literal} need to exclude the parsing of special characters, most often `{`, `}` and `$` in JavaScript and CSS.

There are no such symbols In usual tags like `<script>`, `<style>`, etc. So you can put `{literal}` everywhere you want (but before javasript-code itself).